# Formal proof : predicate logic

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, formal-theory, fitch

This is what I need to prove formally:

```
1.∃x Cube(x) ∧ Small(d)
.
.
.
.
Goal :∃x (Cube(x) ∧ Small(d))
```

I have already tried different ways, but I still can't prove the goal.

```
1. ∃x Cube(x) ∧ Small(d)
2. ∃x Cube(x)         ∧Eilm1
3.Small(d)            ∧Eilm1    
4.∃x Small(x)         ∃intro
```

...

Could you provide some suggestions for how I might prove that?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused what you're trying to prove is identical to your premise... since Small(d) is bound, ∃x only ranges over ∃x Cube(x) part even if it is ^ to something else. Did you miswrite what you need to prove?

Comment: My premise  is  ∃x Cube(x) ∧ Small(d). And my goal is ∃x (Cube(x) ∧ Small(d))

Comment: This is an example where adding extra parenthesis is useful.  I presume what you mean is that your premise is ∃x[Cube(x)] ∧ Small(d)  and your desired conclusion is ∃x [Cube(x) ∧ Small(d)]?

Comment: yes.my premise is ∃x[Cube(x)] ∧ Small(d) and my desired conclusion is ∃x [Cube(x) ∧ Small(d)]

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

```
1. ∃x Cube(x) ∧ Small(d)
2. ∃x Cube(x)      ∧Elim1
3. Small(d)        ∧Elim1    
4. | Cube(z)         A
5. | Cube(z) ^ Small(d) ^Intr 3,4
6. | ∃x(Cube(x) ^ Small(d)) ∃Intr 5
7. ∃x(Cube(x) ^ Small(d)) ∃Elim 2,4-6
```

Comment: i don't think step 4 is right .

Comment: @wenwen fixed it. It's been a while since I used this syntax (See https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Philosophy/LPL-SP/asset/Chapter_13_of_LPL_textbook.pdf)

Comment: But when I type step 5 "Cube(z) ^ Small(d) ^Intr 3,4", the fitch tell me it is not a sentence. How can I do that

Comment: To a large extent, that's fitch being fidly, but you may need to repeat 3 after 4 to be able to ^Intr

Comment: still does't working :(

Comment: @wenwen For what it's worth, I get a correct result with a proof checker using the steps provided in this answer.

Comment: @wenwen I think in Fitch, *z* is a constant, so that 'Cube(z)' is an open sentence. If you use *a* and 'Cube(a)', it should work (even without repeating 3).

Comment: @MarkOxford good to know...

Answer (score 1):

I would start with

```
1. ∃x Cube(x) ∧ Small(d)
2. Small(d)
3. ∃x Cube(x)
```

Which is true because both sides of a true `∧` expression must also be true.

I'd then modify 3 to :

```
4. ∃x [Cube(x)∧T]
```

Because you can always intersect something with True without changing its value.  I can then substitute one true expression(2) for another true expression (T) because they both have the same truth value

```
5. ∃x [Cube(x)∧Small(d)]
```

Comment: what is rule for the step4 ? I have a little confuse

Comment: I don't know what name it would be given, but it's easy to prove with a basic truth table.  For any P and Q,   `Q→(P↔P∧Q) `.  As long as Q is true, you can add conjunctions (and) with it as much as you like without changing the truth value of the expression.  In my case, Q is the very trivial `T`, which leads to `P↔P∧T`. It's like adding 0 or multiplying by 1.